# Where to put the user foreign key in this many to many relationship?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, erd

I have a many to many relationship with bookmarks and tags. Each tag can have many bookmarks, and each bookmark can have many tags.

Users

- Id
- Username

Tags

- Id
- **UserId**
- Title

Bookmarks

- Id
- **UserId**
- Title
- Link

TagsBookmarks *(junction table)*

- TagId
- BookmarkId

I have a reference to an UserId in Tags and Bookmarks table. Is this normalized? The reason I do this is because I sometimes need to load a list of tags that belong to a specific user without bookmarks, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure is valid and normalized.